# HTML not rendering the img after I change src on the run time

Tags: javascript, html, image, file

I have the following code -

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction() 
    {
         var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
         alert(x.value);
         document.getElementById("picture").src=x.value;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="myFile"><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Render this</button>
    <img id="picture" src="C:\Users\Shin\Desktop\410.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

Initailly its showing the image, after I select another file and click the button, it shows me the path in the alert box perfectly but, it doesnt render the new pic and its showing a red cross at the place what you see in image when the src is incorrect. I used chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function myFunction() 
  {
  var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
  var fReader = new FileReader();
  fReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  fReader.onloadend = function(event){
  var img = document.getElementById("picture");
  img.src = event.target.result;
  }  
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="myFile"><br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Render this</button>
  <img id="picture" src="C:\Users\rajpc\Pictures\1390.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

this would definitely work....
Change your img src as desired..
I hope this should help you....

Comment: Some browsers have a security feature that prevents javascript from knowing your file's local full path sometimes it returns somthing called "fakepath.".You can search for it.. It makes sense - as a client, you don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It would be nice if all browsers did this. In order to get rid of this you ahve to use this code..

Answer (score 0):

you'll need URL.createObjectURL for that:

```
url=URL.createObjectURL(x[0]);
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine with my current code when I run it in ie10 and image files I select are jpg or png. but When I start with .svg file I am getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To read a local file you would need to use the FileReader Api.

```
function myFunction() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("picture").src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]);
};
```